# How to make thing take revolution rather than rotation?

Tags: aframe

````
```
<a-entity class="rota" id="duck1" color="#fdfd96" scale="0.1 0.1 .1" position="2 0 -7" animation="property: rotation; to:0 -360 0; loop:true; easing:linear; dur:30000">
            <a-entity class="rota" color="#F0FFF0" gltf-model="spaceship.glb" animation__mouseenter="property: rotation; to:0 360 0; easing:linear; dur:4000; startEvents: mouseenter" position="0 0 1"  scale="2 3 3" collison-check="el: #otherduck; radius: 0.15; other-radius: 0.15;"> </a-entity>
        </a-entity>
```
````

In the first animation it makes the object take the whole revolution in a loop, completing it at specific interval. Whereas, I am using same animation(`animation_mouseenter`) setting inside then it just rotates along y-axis at a fix point given by previously animation. I want animation_mouseenter to work in a manner same as previous one but comparitively faster then previous animation.

In there is another issue as well. Now it just respond to first mouseenter call but not later. I know this is because I have not used `from` in animation_mouseenter. But I don't want animation to start from one particular location, rather I want it to occur whenever there's a mouse over the entity.

Answer (score 0):

The outer entity is a parent of the inner entity.

The inner entity's position is set relative to the parent (outer) entity.

When you rotate the outer entity, you will see the inner entity moving round in a cicle, around a pivot point that is the position of the outer entity.

When you rotate the inner entity, you are just rotating the inner entity, so it will just spin on its own axis.

An analogy: imagine a cookie on the edge of a plate.  The outer animation is likely spinning the plate: the cookie moves around.  The inner animation is like spinning the cookie: it stays still and just spins.

For the effect you want, I think you need to move the inner animation onto the outer entity (spin the plate, not the cookie).

You can still trigger it with the mouseover event because the mouseover event will bubble up from child to parent.  Alternatively, you could use a small component to relay events from one object to another (here's an existing component that could help you to do that https://github.com/diarmidmackenzie/key-bindings).